In compose multiplatform, ios throws error on load image
I am using compose multiplatform
I'm currently working on a project using Compose Multiplatform project, and looking for ways to handle image loading from a URL. While sync I get error
Error:
:composeApp:iosArm64Main: Could not find io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-network-ktor:3.0.0-rc01.
Required by:
project :composeApp
toml version file
[version]
kotlin = "2.0.20"
coil = "3.0.0-rc01"
ktor = "3.0.0"

[libraries]
ktor-core = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-core", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-darwin = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-okhttp = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-js = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-js", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-curl = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-curl", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-winhttp = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-winhttp", version.ref = "ktor" }
coil-compose = { module = "io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-compose", version.ref = "coil" }
coil-compose-core = { module = "io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-compose-core", version.ref = "coil" }
coil-network-ktor = { module = "io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-network-ktor", version.ref = "coil" }
coil-mp = { module = "io.coil-kt.coil3:coil", version.ref = "coil" }

here is my gradle
sourceSets {
        
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)

            //coil
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.okhttp)


        }

        iosMain.dependencies {

            //coil
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
        }

        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.compose)

            //coil
            implementation(libs.ktor.core)
            implementation(libs.coil.compose.core)
            implementation(libs.coil.mp)
            implementation(libs.coil.network.ktor)
            implementation(libs.coil.compose)
        }
    }

Can any one tell me what is wring here.

It's because of the version numbers on Maven. The other libraries you are importing are at 3.0.0-rc01, but the most recent version available for io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-network-ktor is 3.0.0-alpha08. If you update your toml with
[version]
...
coil-network = "3.0.0-alpha08"

and change your coil-network-ktor library to
coil-network-ktor = { module = "io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-network-ktor", version.ref = "coil-network" }

it should fix the issue.

Didn't fix for me

I didn't find what is wrong in your code, max is what I feel is wrong is
    //ktor
    implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)

    //coil
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:3.0.0")

in iosMain these two are the same.
I can share my dependencies I have no issue with loading.
androidMain.dependencies {
       .....
        implementation(libs.ktor.client.android)
    }
commonMain.dependencies {
        ...
        implementation(libs.coil)
        implementation(libs.coil.compose)
        implementation(libs.coil.ktor)
    }
iosMain.dependencies {
        implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
    }


I updated my description with full details and error, can you check please. Thanks

also can you show your version.toml file and gradle file

coil = "3.0.0-alpha06"
#COIL
coil = { module = "io.coil-kt.coil3:coil", version.ref = "coil" }
coil-compose = { module = "io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-compose", version.ref = "coil" }
coil-compose-core = { module = "io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-compose-core", version.ref = "coil" }
coil-ktor = { module = "io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-network-ktor", version.ref = "coil" }
coil-compose-core hasn't been used

Could you tell me how did u get this  implementation(libs.ktor.client.android)
Its not mentioned in toml file.  Also please look into my question. I updated full description

ktor-client-core = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-core", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-darwin = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-android = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-android", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-serialization-json = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-content-negotiation = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation", version.ref = "ktor" } all ktor dependencies
